# How to let the browser know that there's a new version of the file fetched, and force to invalidate cache?

Tags: amazon-s3, caching, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket with static files. Every time I update the bucket with new version of each file, I set the cache-control to cache files for a month, and then invalidate the cloudfront cache.

If I have an index.html file that's fetched by the browser, and has a cached version of it, how can I let the user's browser know that there is a new version of that file, and the cache should be invalidated, and the new version should be fetched?

I was reading [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html) about S3 sending `LastModified` header to cloudfront, and it then compares the version that's cached if it has the same value for it. I was wondering if cloudfront forwards this header to the browser through cloudfront as well, and the user's browser automatically detects that there has been a change.

I was testing this, and what I've found is that I have to refresh twice in order for the changes to be reflected in my browser.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions on here you should look at. Briefly, there's no mechanism in HTTP to invalidate a cached resource while it's still fresh. `Last-Modified` and `ETag` are used to revalidate a resource after the cache time has expired. Check the MDN articles on these topics as well.